# Calculating power using a for loop instead of applying the Math.pow method

Tags: java, for-loop

Trying a method to find the power of a number using a for loop and without using Math.pow. For this result I just got 2.0 as it doesn't seem to go back round through the loop. Help please.

```
public void test() {
         {
                double t = 1; 
                double b = 2; // base number
                double exponent = 2;

                for (int i = 1; i<=exponent; i++); 
                    t = t*b;

                    System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Remove that semicolon following the `for` line.

Comment: Also why does i start at 2?

Comment: Thank you, it was just the semi-colon, works now!

Comment: yes just noticed that also. I posted starting at two by mistake. Was experimenting with the code and hadn't noticed that I still had the 2 there, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
double t = 1; 
double b = 2; // base number
double exponent = 2;
for (int i = 1; i<=exponent; i++) t = t*b;
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: @SteveChalmers if this help you, could you accept it?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first iteration around you are setting T equal to B. You aren't multiplying by the exponent just yet. So it needs to iterate 1 further time then you are expecting. just decrease the I value in your for loop. EG

```
for(int i = 1; i <= exponent; i++)
    t=t*b;
```

Hope this helps!